# How do I fix these build errors in Unreal?

Tags: unreal-4, build-process, inverse-kinematics, error-management

I am using [this](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/control-rig-mannequin) asset to do some IK magic in UE4.

I connected some nodes to control the rig realtime.
It works fine, I hooked up some dummy cube actor to control the limbs of the rig and that works fine, the limbs are moving OK.

When I try to build I get a nasty error message, please see below.

As far as I understand, it is yelling because I took the editor time values and gave it runtime ones...For some reason it can't see it when you are building your project.

When I exit the editor, I have to reconnect the same control rig nodes causing the error message...

I also run into post about setting the project version, to no avail.

When I hit package for Windows I get packaging errors:

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: begin: stack for UAT
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: === Handled ensure: ===
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: Ensure condition failed: false [File:D:/Build/++UE4+Licensee/Sync/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/ControlRig/Source/ControlRigDeveloper/Private/AnimGraphNode_ControlRig.cpp] [Line: 112]
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: Stack:
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd90a55b9 UE4Editor-ControlRigDeveloper.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbd907e1dc UE4Editor-ControlRigDeveloper.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbe9f816b8 UE4Editor-BlueprintGraph.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbe9f29b57 UE4Editor-BlueprintGraph.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbedc4f58d UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbeabdc446 UE4Editor-Kismet.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbeabda615 UE4Editor-Kismet.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4d6cd40 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4f715e4 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4f9877a UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4f7003c UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4f71acb UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4f998b0 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf50dd352 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4fdcdcd UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4fdb4b3 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4fdd001 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4fdad73 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4f7fba0 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4fd8f3f UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4f73c11 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf4f8c90e UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf50dcfe0 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf50dc420 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbed7040fd UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbed7447f5 UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbed5b1031 UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbed5dbd5b UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff691d4363a UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff691d3b7ec UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff691d3bb5a UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff691d4e31d UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff691d5040a UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffc3de96fd4 KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffc3dfdcec1 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogOutputDevice: Error: end: stack for UAT
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogBlueprint: Error: [Compiler ThirdPersonCharacter] In use pin  Leg Controller  no longer exists on node  Get . Please refresh node or break links to remove pin. from Source: /Game/ThirdPersonBP/Blueprints/ThirdPersonCharacter.ThirdPersonCharacter
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogBlueprint: Error: [Compiler ThirdPersonCharacter] The property associated with  Left Leg Controller  could not be found in '/Game/ThirdPersonBP/Blueprints/ThirdPersonCharacter.ThirdPersonCharacter_C' from Source: /Game/ThirdPersonBP/Blueprints/ThirdPersonCharacter.ThirdPersonCharacter
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogBlueprint: Error: [Compiler PersistentLevel.RTT_Main] Spawn node  Create Widget  must have a class specified. from Source: /Game/GizmoPluginBPs/RTT_Shared/RTT_Main.RTT_Main:PersistentLevel.RTT_Main
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogBlueprint: Error: [Compiler PersistentLevel.RTTM_Login] Spawn node  Create Widget  must have a class specified. from Source: /Game/GizmoPluginBPs/RTT_MultiPlayerExample/RTTM_Login.RTTM_Login:PersistentLevel.RTTM_Login
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogBlueprint: Error: [Compiler RTTM_TransformerPawn] Spawn node  Create Widget  must have a class specified. from Source: /Game/GizmoPluginBPs/RTT_MultiPlayerExample/RTTM_TransformerPawn.RTTM_TransformerPawn
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogBlueprint: Error: [Compiler RTTM_TransformerPawn] In use pin  <Unnamed>  no longer exists on node  Change Selected . Please refresh node or break links to remove pin. from Source: /Game/GizmoPluginBPs/RTT_MultiPlayerExample/RTTM_TransformerPawn.RTTM_TransformerPawn
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogBlueprint: Error: [Compiler RTTM_TransformerPawn] In use pin  Target  no longer exists on node  Change Selected . Please refresh node or break links to remove pin. from Source: /Game/GizmoPluginBPs/RTT_MultiPlayerExample/RTTM_TransformerPawn.RTTM_TransformerPawn
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogBlueprint: Error: [Compiler RTTM_TransformerPawn] In use pin  Component  no longer exists on node  Change Selected . Please refresh node or break links to remove pin. from Source: /Game/GizmoPluginBPs/RTT_MultiPlayerExample/RTTM_TransformerPawn.RTTM_TransformerPawn
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogInit: Display: LogBlueprint: Error: [Compiler RTTM_TransformerPawn] In use pin  Selected  no longer exists on node  Change Selected . Please refresh node or break links to remove pin. from Source: /Game/GizmoPluginBPs/RTT_MultiPlayerExample/RTTM_TransformerPawn.RTTM_TransformerPawn
```

Comment: Look at the last few lines detailing errors with your Leg Controller.